# Convert text value in SQL Server from GB2312 to WINDOWS-1251

Tags: sql-server, cp1251, gb2312, windows-1251

I have a column in SQL Server with GB2312 Chinese_PRC_CI_AS encoding. How can I convert and save the text in WINDOWS-1251 encoding? I would like to do thing in a query on SQL Server. Any tips?

Comment: Encoding is mostly transparent in SQL Server (you'll get the same string on the client end no matter how the characters are encoded), so it's not clear what your scenario is. Doubly so because Windows-1251 cannot encode any Chinese characters. Do you want to change the column collation?

Comment: `nvarchar` would probably be a better idea

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "data conversion" component, and then you can select the code page for it